# Matlab image interpolation interp2()

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

let `img1`, and `img2` represent two images with the same dimensions; and let `v = (tx,ty)` be a vector representing shifting (translation) of the `img1` toward `img2`.
how can I use `interp2()` to warp `img2` towards `img1`?

Comment: Are img1 and img2 parts of the same image? Can you give an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I might guess you meant warp?

Comment: @Andrey, it was a typo. i meant "warp"

Comment: @Phonon, i have two images, such that one is a shifting of the other. the shifting values are stored within vector _v_. i would like to move one image towards the other (align them).

Comment: Is it just shifting i.e. translation you want to do? Or are there more transformations on the image? In the first case you could do it by copying the image to the appropriated indices of a bigger image (matrix). What are the dimensions?

Comment: Since you know `v` you just have to displace `img2` by `-v`.

Answer (score 0):

Define the grid for which the images are defined

```
>> sz = size(img1);
>> [y x] = ndgrid( 1:sz(1), 1:sz(2) );
```

Use the grid to define the interpolation

```
>> timg2 = interp( x, y, img2, x + tx, y + ty );
```

PS,
You might want to take a look at `tformarray` to do the same.

Comment: did you mean interp2? For my color image, i'm getting that "Transpose on ND array is not defined." for V.